# Weak solution of heat equation decreases in time

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, heat-equation

Let $u_t - \Delta u = f$ hold with some appropriate initial condition and Dirichlet boundary condition on some smooth bounded domain. We take $f$ to be negative.

Does anyone know a citation that states the result that the solution is decaying/decreasing in time? I.e. I want an $L^\infty$ decay result of the form

$$|u(t,x)| \leq F(t)$$ where $F$ is decreasing in $t$.

Answer (score 1):

How about multiplying by $u$ and integrating over space?

$$u\partial_{t}u-u\triangle u=uf$$

Integrating shows that:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int u^{2}+\int |\nabla u|^{2}=\int uf$$

This shows that $u$ should be decreasing. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Doesn't that just show that the integral of $u$ is decreasing?

Comment: You know that $u\geq 0$, and so $\int u\geq 0$.